# Get the process id of ShellExecute

Tags: focus, handle, shellexecute

I have been searching all day to find a solution to this problem.
I have 2 Excel instances (2 times launched) and in one a batch process is running to create a pdf file. If I use ShellExecute to start the conversion then the focus is not switched to the called application and the user can continue in the other excel application without interuptions.
There is altough a problem, the ShellExecute does not wait and so this is runing square. I tryed with ShellExecuteEx with the nescessary options set but this steals the focus anyhow. So my only chance is ShellExecute but I should be able to get the id of the process created so I can wait until ended. A long explaination but I found it nescessary. Who can help me here ?

Comment: This doesn't answer the literal question in your title, but I think it accomplishes what you are trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374433/

Comment: I tryed this one but like stated above this steals the focus; interupting the doings of the user.