# vba shell fails in excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I have charts in excel that I copy and pass to an external picture manager with flags by the Shell command to save each chart as a gif. In Excel 2003 it works fine, but in 2016 it fails. I have tried wrapping the string with double quotes even there is no space in it, no luck. However, if I print out the string with *debug.print ShComd* and input that, then it works in 2016, like:

```
ShComd="C:\IrfanView\i_view32.exe ... =C:\Test\Sheet1.gif /killmesoftly"
```

So this fails only in 2016 in row PID = ... with *wrong argument*

```
ShComd = i_view_Path & "\i_view32.exe /clippaste /convert=" _
& SavePath & "\" & Sht.Name & ".gif /killmesoftly"   
For Each Chrt In Sht.ChartObjects
    Chrt.Copy
    DoEvents
    Sleep (250) 'start up irfanview to avoid "Can't Load"
    PID = Shell(ShComd) 'fails here in 2016
Next Chrt
```

How come?

Comment: 32-bit Office, or 64-bit?

Comment: I think the XL2016 is in 32bit (on win10) (Can't access it until monday to double check)

Comment: The chart's `Export` method doesn't do what you need here?

Comment: Maybe try [something else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1374433/2392157)?

Comment: Thank's @Tim Williams , yes a much better method in this case!!! I didn't know it was there :) The tip from mirixlav is also useful for running shells, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Billy, I'd first reference the library, *Windows Script Host Object Model.* Then, use the Run method. And, most important for your concern, separate the multiple commands with " && "

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command).